# the tornado bomb

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, childrens-novel, space-station

I once read a children's short story about a couple kids who visit a space station with their dad. While there, the station weather forcaster notices a tornado has formed, and is heading straight for their home - and their mom - back in the midwest somewhere. The station fires a "Tornado Bomb" from orbit, which blows up the storm before it can take out their house.

It was a pretty old story, probably early 1950s, aimed at fairly young kids. Maybe fourth graders or so. When I read it, it was part of an anthology that included a couple other stories involving the same kids, as well as several other completely unrelated stories. Presumably those were by different authors.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It might be worth mentioning the descriptions of any other stories in the anthology that you can remember.

Comment: Sadly, I don't really remember any of the others in any detail. The book was probably part of the post-Colliers period where everyone was cranking out stories to show the practical applications of space, such as (in this case) weather forecasting and weather modification. That would probably mean the book was compiled no earlier than 1952-1954. It was definitely intended to be educational.

Comment: The closest thing I could find was Philip Palmer's "Artemis", which is the only thing I could find with the words "tornado bomb" in it. However, it's not for kids, and I don't think it's the right story.